# how can I solve the error with fastcgi in config processmaker?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, processmaker

when I was trying to install processmaker stackN220 I occured error.
the support team of processmaker did not answer any question in intercom chat because I'm not enterprise customer!

my conf is :

```
#ProcessMaker HTTP Virtual Host

server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  #Change for server DNS name
  server_name processmakernginx.local;
  #The following line must be added Only if phpMyAdmin is configured
  #include /opt/phpMyAdmin/phpMyAdmin.conf;

  root /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html; #where ProcessMaker is installed

  index index.html index.htm app.php index.php;

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  charset utf-8;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  access_log /var/log/nginx/pm-access.log combined; #enables access logs

  error_log  /var/log/nginx/pm-error.log error; #enables error logs

  sendfile off;

  client_max_body_size 100m;

 # Every PHP script must be routed to PHP-FPM

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/processmaker.sock;
    fastcgi_index    app.php;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME  /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html/app.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

  }

 #Browser Caching

  location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpeg|jpg|png|woff|ttf|otf|svg|woff2|eot)$ {
    expires 24h;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/processmaker.sock;

    fastcgi_index    app.php;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME   /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html/app.php;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;

    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;

    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;

    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;

    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
 }


 location ~ /\.ht {
   deny all;
 }

 error_page 404 /404.html;
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 }

}
```

but error

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

occurred.

and when call url, first a html file redirect it to

```
http://processmakernginx.local/sys/en/neoclassic/login/login
```

mannual: https://wiki.processmaker.com/3.2/Stack_N220

```
file not found
```

appeared.

Comment: facing same issue, Are you able to find the solution?

Comment: I don't remember. let's check one of my severs and paste correct in answer

Answer (score 0):

the configuration is correct.
you may missed the app.php file in /opt/processmaker/workflow/public_html

Answer (score 0):

May be nginx user hasn't permission to  /opt/processmaker .